# What is the best way to test if a CharacterSet contains a Character in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm looking for a way, in Swift 4, to test if a Character is a member of an arbitrary CharacterSet.  I have this `Scanner` class that will be used for some lightweight parsing.  One of the functions in the class is to skip any characters, at the current position, that belong to a certain set of possible characters.

```
class MyScanner {
  let str: String
  var idx: String.Index
  init(_ string: String) {
    str = string
    idx = str.startIndex
  }
  var remains: String { return String(str[idx..<str.endIndex])}

  func skip(charactersIn characters: CharacterSet) {
    while idx < str.endIndex && characters.contains(str[idx])) {
      idx = source.index(idx, offsetBy: 1)
    }
  }
}

let scanner = MyScanner("fizz   buzz fizz")
scanner.skip(charactersIn: CharacterSet.alphanumerics)
scanner.skip(charactersIn: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
print("what remains: \"\(scanner.remains)\"")
```

I would like to implement the `skip(charactersIn:)` function so that the above code would print `buzz fizz`.

The tricky part is `characters.contains(str[idx]))` in the `while` - `.contains()` requires a `Unicode.Scalar`, and I'm at a loss trying to figure out the next step.

I know I could pass in a `String` to the `skip` function, but I'd like to find a way to make it work with a `CharacterSet`, because of all the convenient static members (`alphanumerics`, `whitespaces`, etc.).

How does one test a `CharacterSet` if it contains a `Character`?

Comment: There is a system class called `NSScanner`, bridged into Swift as `Scanner`. Have you checked it out?

Comment: NSScanner sure does look like a wheel I'm re-inventing at first blush. Not crazy about the NS semantics (uses an inout `NSString?` param), but it might do the trick. Out of curiosity, I looked through the [source](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/Scanner.swift), and it converts a `String` to an `Array<unichar>`, and it's `skip` function then just uses `set.contains(UnicodeScalar(currentCharacter)!)`.

Comment: If you don't like the NS semantics of `NSScanner`, then use Foundation's `Scanner`, which doesn't use NS types. Certainly don't define your own class with the name of an existing class. That's just going to be confusing.

Comment: Good point re: class name (edited question). Foundation's Scanner still requires an NSString as a receiving inout parameter: `func scanCharacters(from set: CharacterSet, into result: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know that you wanted to use `CharacterSet` rather than `String`, but `CharacterSet` does not (yet, at least) support characters that are composed of more than one `Unicode.Scalar`. See the "family" character (‍‍‍) or the international flag characters (e.g. "" or "") that Apple demonstrated in the string discussion in WWDC 2017 video [What's New in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/402/). The multiple skin tone emoji also manifest this behavior (e.g.  vs ).

As a result, I'd be wary of using `CharacterSet` (which is a "set of Unicode character values for use in search operations"). Or, if you want to provide this method for the sake of convenience, be aware that it will not work correctly with characters represented by multiple unicode scalars.

So, you might offer a scanner that provides both `CharacterSet` and `String` renditions of the `skip` method:

```
class MyScanner {
    let string: String
    var index: String.Index

    init(_ string: String) {
        self.string = string
        index = string.startIndex
    }

    var remains: String { return String(string[index...]) }

    /// Skip characters in a string
    ///
    /// This rendition is safe to use with strings that have characters
    /// represented by more than one unicode scalar.
    ///
    /// - Parameter skipString: A string with all of the characters to skip.

    func skip(charactersIn skipString: String) {
        while index < string.endIndex, skipString.contains(string[index]) {
            index = string.index(index, offsetBy: 1)
        }
    }

    /// Skip characters in character set
    ///
    /// Note, character sets cannot (yet) include characters that are represented by
    /// more than one unicode scalar (e.g. ‍‍‍ or  or ). If you want to test
    /// for these multi-unicode characters, you have to use the `String` rendition of
    /// this method.
    ///
    /// This will simply stop scanning if it encounters a multi-unicode character in
    /// the string being scanned (because it knows the `CharacterSet` can only represent
    /// single-unicode characters) and you want to avoid false positives (e.g., mistaking
    /// the Jamaican flag, , for the Japanese flag, ).
    ///
    /// - Parameter characterSet: The character set to check for membership.

    func skip(charactersIn characterSet: CharacterSet) {
        while index < string.endIndex,
            string[index].unicodeScalars.count == 1,
            let character = string[index].unicodeScalars.first,
            characterSet.contains(character) {
                index = string.index(index, offsetBy: 1)
        }
    }

}
```

Thus, your simple example will still work:

```
let scanner = MyScanner("fizz   buzz fizz")
scanner.skip(charactersIn: CharacterSet.alphanumerics)
scanner.skip(charactersIn: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
print(scanner.remains)  // "buzz fizz"
```

But use the `String` rendition if the characters you want to skip might include multiple unicode scalars:

```
let family = "\u{200D}\u{200D}\u{200D}"  // ‍‍‍
let boy = ""

let charactersToSkip = family + boy

let string = boy + family + "foobar"  // ‍‍‍foobar

let scanner = MyScanner(string)
scanner.skip(charactersIn: charactersToSkip)
print(scanner.remains)                // foobar
```

---

As Michael Waterfall noted in the comments below, `CharacterSet` has a bug and doesn’t even handle 32-bit `Unicode.Scalar` values correctly, meaning that it doesn’t even handle single scalar characters properly if the value exceeds `0xffff` (including emoji, amongst others). The `String` rendition, above, handles these correctly, though.

Comment: Interestingly `CharacterSet` doesn't even handle emoji that is represented with a single unicode scalar ( = 128518) however this returns `false`:
`CharacterSet(charactersIn: "ABC").contains(UnicodeScalar(128518)!)`

Comment: Yeah, above and beyond the single scalar limitation of character sets, there's obviously a bug in `CharacterSet`'s handling of 32-bit scalars, handling them like 16-bit scalars. E.g. try looking in your string for `Unicode.Scalar(62982)` (i.e. `128518 && 0xffff`); lol. It all works fine and dandy with 16-bit scalars, but it's a train wreck when you try using 32-bit scalars with values exceeding `UInt16.max`. We should file a bug report. I'm happy to do so, unless you'd rather do it.

Comment: `index = string.index(index, offsetBy: 1)` there is a "mutating" method for this `string.formIndex(after: &index)`

Answer (score 16):

Not sure if it's the most efficient way but you can create a new CharSet and check if they are sub/super-sets (Set comparison is rather quick)

```
let newSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "a")
// let newSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\(character)")
print(newSet.isSubset(of: CharacterSet.decimalDigits)) // false
print(newSet.isSubset(of: CharacterSet.alphanumerics)) // true
```

Comment: This was the perfect solution for me

Comment: or `CharacterSet.decimalDigits.isSuperset(of: newSet)`

Answer (score 13):

**Swift 4.2**
`CharacterSet` extension function to check whether it contains `Character`:

```
extension CharacterSet {
    func containsUnicodeScalars(of character: Character) -> Bool {
        return character.unicodeScalars.allSatisfy(contains(_:))
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
CharacterSet.decimalDigits.containsUnicodeScalars(of: "3") // true
CharacterSet.decimalDigits.containsUnicodeScalars(of: "a") // false
```

Comment: Yeah actually nice one, this totally did work for my case

Comment: I wonder if it would be okay to assume that if character.unicodeScalars.count is != 1 there is no match possible at least for most use cases?